# SQL SELECT JOIN multiple tables

Tags: sql, join, select, left-join, outer-join

I want to select all conventions that has not specialties or has the specialties that are in the given array.

**convention**

| convention_id | type |
| --- | --- |
| **1c** | ty1 |
| 2c | ty2 |
| 3c | ty3 |

**activity_type**

| activity_type_id | effect_date | motif | fk_convention |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1a** | xxxxx | nothi | **1c** |
| 2a | xxxxx | abc | 1c |
| 3a | xxxxx | def | 2c |
| 4a | xxxxx | poi | 3c |

**activity_type_specialties**

| fk_activity_type | fk_specialty |
| --- | --- |
| **1a** | **1s** |
| 1a | 2s |
| 2a | 3s |
| 4a | 3s |

**speciality**

| speciality_id | label |
| --- | --- |
| **1s** | PEDIATRIE |
| 2s | GERIATRIE |
| 3s | NEPHROLOGIE |

For an array ['1s'], the query must return the conventions 1c et 2c (the convention 1c contains the specialties 1s and 2s, and the convention 2c has not any specialties )

Comment: Also specify the expected result. ([mcve].)

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand the question, as your expected result sounds other then the first question.. but i hope that can help:

```
select c.convention_id, c.type, a.*, at.*  from convention c
left join activity_type a on (a.fk_convention = c.convention_id)
left join activity_type_specialties at on (at.fk_activity_type = a.activity_type_id)
where at.fk_specialty is null
```

Martin

Answer (score -1):

I hope the answer helps.

```
    select fk_specialty,fk_convertion from convertion c
    inner join activity_type a on c.convertion_id=a.fk_convertion
    inner join activity_type_specialties ats on 
    ats.fk_activity_type=a.activity_type_id
    inner join speciality s on s.speciality_id=ats.fk_specialty
    where fk_specialty in ('1c','2c')
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. If you don't fully understand the question you are better-off asking a question or two, instead of offering an answer.  This is because other users of stackoverflow will see that a question has an answer (maybe incorrect) and maybe not even try to give a better answer.